# PGFplots Tikz plot two or more added expressions in different domains

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fpu

Basically I want to use PGFplots/tikzs to plot the sum of two expressions, but the first expression - let's name it `f(x)` - is specified within `0<=x<=1000` and the second expression - let's name it `g(x)` - should only be specified within `100<=x<=200` but is unfortunately not equal zero in the regions outside of `100<=x<=200`. I just want to add the two functions `(f(x)+g(x))` and plot the result with a single `\addplot` command within the full domain `0<=x<=1000`, with `g(x)` being zero outside of `100<=x<=200`.

Do you know a flexible and easy way to achieve the desired bahavior with a single `\addplot[...][domain=0:1000]{...}` command, as the only solution I found (but some sort of don't like - as it forces me to plot three different functions) is plotting

```
1. \addplot ... f(domain: 0<=x<100)
2. \addplot ... f(domain: 200<x<=1000)
3. \addplot ... f+g(domain: 100<=x<=200)
```

as a workaround.

PS: I want to avoid solutions that involve gnuplot or having to store the data within files or something like that... I'd prefer to have a solution that works with the following packages/libraries within the preamble `\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,grffile,amsmath}` and `\usetikzlibrary{fpu}` but feel free to post the most easy solution.

I hope you don't mind that I didn't include any MWE and that the syntax I provided within the description is actually not 'fully working syntax' but just some sort of symbolic excerpts that provide the key to understand my problem.

Comment: I think you actually mean `1000` in `\addplot ... f(domain: 0<=x<100)`, don't you ?

Comment: No it was correct: only within `100<=x<=200` I want the function `f(x)+g(x)` and within the rest (`0<=x<100` and `200<x<=1000`) I only want `f(x)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do pgfmath if then else inside math expressions.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
% Cancel f(x) until 2 then after 4 shift it with 40
\addplot+[no marks,domain=0:6,samples=301] { -x^2 + ( x<2 ? x+x^2 : ( x>4 ? 40 : 0) ) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am going to mark your answer as solution, as it is very convenient and a little easier than the answer of @marsupilam. The solution I am using looks like this: `%\addplot+[no marks,domain=0:1000,samples=1000] {( x>200 ? f(x) : ( x>=100 ? f(x)+g(x) : f(x) ) )};`

Is there not an easier way to get the same result, e.g. a logical AND or similar?:  `%\addplot+[...] {( x<=200 && x>=100  ? f(x)+g(x) : f(x) )};`

Comment: @phw This is in my answer ! `\addplot+[...] {f(x) + (x<=200)*(x>=100)*g(x)} ;` Also the `&&` operator is documented at page 927 in the [PGF-TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

You can truncate your functions by using boolean multipliers.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\def\omeg{.1}
\def\A{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    declare function=
    {
      f(\x) = 1/\omeg * (1.5+sin( .1 * \omeg * deg(\x)));
      g(\x) = (100<=\x) * (\x<=200) * \A/\omeg * (1+sin(\omeg*deg(\x)));
    }
  ]
  \begin{axis}
    [
      %{{{
      domain = 0:1000,
      samples = 201,
      axis lines = center,
      %}}}
    ]

    \addplot+[mark=none] {f(x)};
    \addplot+[mark=none, domain=100:200] {g(x)};
    \addplot+[mark=none] {f(x) + g(x)};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```